# Can a CUDA 'dot product' kernel accelerate bulk RMS computation?

Tags: c++, performance, cuda, dot-product

New to CUDA here but hoping its use might reduce the amount of time that single-threaded CPU code takes to compute root-mean-squares (specifically, the RMS of each of the `u` contiguous disjoint sub-arrays of length `v` contained in an array `A` of length `u*v` housing floats between 1 and -1).

I had hoped to use [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/scalarProd) sample to do the vast majority of the work*, but am finding that even the 1st step of separating `A`'s sub-arrays with `0`s for memory coalescing purposes (which I'm doing via single-threaded CPU code) takes longer than the entire CPU-based RMS calculation using 'ballpark' values `u=200`, `v=5000`!

I'm vaguely aware that there might be a way to apply padding at the same time `A` is copied to device memory, as I am that perhaps a second kernel could be used to perform the padding, but am not sure if exploring these approaches is worthwhile. I'm also aware of Thrust and cuBLAS, but the linked sample seems to my simple mind more likely to provide the desired acceleration (given that some care must be taken to prepare kernel input).

Are the 'ballpark' values above (which are similar to those in the sample) simply too small to allow the GPU to come into its own? Neither number is likely to be able to be raised to the next power of 10, alas. Would be very grateful for any input from those a little more familiar with GPU computing than myself. FWIW, here's the single-threaded CPU code I'm trying to improve upon (`rms` function) and a little context for it:

```cpp
const size_t num     = 5000; // might be able to increase by a factor of <2
const size_t numSegs =  200; // might be able to increase by a factor of <5

float rms(const float a[], const size_t origin, const size_t length)
{
    float sumOfSquares = 0.0f;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        sumOfSquares += a[origin + i] * a[origin + i];

    return std::sqrt(sumOfSquares / float(length));
}

int main()
{
    ...

    float* array = (float*)malloc(num * numSegs * sizeof(float));
    float* RMSes = (float*)malloc(numSegs * sizeof(float));

    // array fill omitted; A[i] lies between -1 and 1 inclusive

    for (size_t segNum = 0; segNum < numSegs; ++segNum)
    {
        RMSes[segNum] = rms(array, segNum * num, num);
    }
    ...
}
```

*given that RMS(A)=sqrt(B/C), where B is 'A dot A' and C is A's length

### Edit:

The CUDA-based approach is certainly working, but is currently a lot slower than host code

### Edit (again):

- Targeted CPUs: x86
- Targeted GPU : RTX3070 ("Ampere" with compute capability 8.6)

### Execution times:

- loop in `main()` (above): 2227-2259us (6 runs)
- loop in `main()` using `dot_product_avx2` from below answer by @Michaël Roy: 445-491us (3 runs)
- padding `array[]`:        2279-3748us (6 runs)
- lines 119-134 of [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/scalarProd/scalarProd.cu) (not lines passing `&hTimer`) + compute RMSs using `h_C_GPU`: 2050-2306us (3 runs)
- lines 119-134 of [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/scalarProd/scalarProd.cu) (not lines passing `&hTimer`) + compute RMSs using `h_C_GPU` **without padding** `array[]`: 2125-2382us (3 runs)

Very surprised to see how little effect padding had on the GPU-based approach despite the sample's advice that

> `ElementN` is strongly preferred to be a multiple of warp size to meet alignment constraints of memory coalescing.

The parallel code is simply a minimally-modified version of the linked sample. `VECTOR_N` corresponds to `u`, `ELEMENT_N` to the smallest number greater than `v` that's divisible by warp size, `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice` appears only once, `A[i]` may be negative, `StopWatchInterface`-related code is omitted, and each dot product in `h_C_GPU` is used to compute an RMS value.

Comment: Are your targeting x86 cpu's ?

Comment: Skip this first step, but in the first iteration inside the CUDA rms function for reading the data to be squared instead of all 32 threads of a warp reading data, only the last n (=1..32) threads read data dependent on the address n = 32 - (origin % 32). Make 32 threads do each segment. They should sum up their individual squares and do a warp reduction afterwards.

Comment: For storing back you could collect several RMS results in shared memory to write in a coalesced way, but this would be only a marginal gain. For reading you could read 32 elements for the first and last iteration over shared memory, this also would give you marginal gains. In both cases the 2nd level cache already helps a lot. Overall, you won't be able to run your kernel faster than a few microseconds due to minimal startup overhead. For Cuda runtime do exclude overall Cuda initialization and allocation of memory.

Comment: It would be great to know what hardware (CPU and GPU) you are targeting and how long the sequential code takes. Is this the only operation done on the GPU (i.e. copies from and to device memory need to be compensated for)? How exactly are you measuring performance? If your GPU is not in persistence mode, the first kernel call will often be quite slow.

Comment: Indeed - I tried submitting a comment on your answer but it has disappeared! @Michaël Roy

Comment: @yodawasacoder  I had uploaeded the wrong version for sse2.  It's back on

Comment: @paleonix Coding on a PC with a Ryzen 5 3600 and a RTX3070 ("Ampere" with CC 8.6), which are my only targets at this point. The loop in main() above takes 0.00099999s as measured by clock() from time.h. 1ms is also (per clock()) the total time taken to do all of: both host/device memory copies, kernel execution, and RMS calculations given the dot products the kernel supplies. The problem is that padding array[] takes 32ms! The parallel code is simply a minimally-modified (e.g. use GPU-computed dot products to calculate RMSs) version of the linked sample. I'll investigate persistence mode - thx

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for posting - as a CUDA newbie I only got the gist of the comment beginning 'For storing back...'. I believe I'm measuring the running time correctly (tho' maybe not as precisely as possible) and am indeed aware of the 'lower bound' on this value due to the startup overhead - cheers

Comment: When you are asked for more information in the comments on SO, please add the information to your question instead of commenting it. Not everyone will read the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an implementation using Thrust/CUB. It should serve as a reference in terms of performance for any CUDA solution that you come up with. As the CUB algorithm does not know about the regularity of your problem, it should totally be possible to write a faster CUDA implementation than this one in theory. But getting a significant speedup over this reference might be highly non-trivial in practice.

This problem is totally suitable for GPU-computing, but your problem size might still be too small for the GPU to shine.

I decided to use `cub::DeviceSegmentedReduce` instead of `thrust::reduce_by_key` (which uses CUB in the backend) here for better performance and because it is easier to get around measuring the overhead of allocating temporary storage.

```cpp
#include <cmath>

#include <iostream>

#include <cub/cub.cuh>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_output_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/random/uniform_real_distribution.h>

constexpr size_t num     = 5000; // might be able to increase by a factor of <2
constexpr size_t numSegs =  200; // might be able to increase by a factor of <5

template <typename T>
class ScaleBy
{
    T factor_;

    public:
    ScaleBy(T factor) noexcept : factor_{factor} {}

    __host__ __device__
    T operator()(T val) const noexcept { return factor_ * val; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Square
{
    __host__ __device__
    T operator()(T val) const noexcept { return val * val; }
};

template <typename T>
class RootMean
{
    T norm_;

    public:
    RootMean(T norm) noexcept : norm_{norm} {}

    __host__ __device__
    T operator()(T sum) const noexcept { return sqrt(sum / norm_); }
};

void segmented_rms_device(thrust::device_vector<float> const &d_array,
                          thrust::device_vector<float> &d_RMSes,
                          uint8_t *d_temp_storage,
                          size_t &temp_storage_bytes)
{
    auto seg_size = d_array.size() / d_RMSes.size();
    auto origin_iter = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(0ull),
        ScaleBy<size_t>{seg_size});
    auto input_iter = thrust::make_transform_iterator(
        d_array.cbegin(),
        Square<float>{});
    auto output_iter = thrust::make_transform_output_iterator(
        d_RMSes.begin(),
        RootMean<float>{static_cast<float>(seg_size)});

    cub::DeviceSegmentedReduce::Sum(d_temp_storage,
                                    temp_storage_bytes,
                                    input_iter,
                                    output_iter, numSegs,
                                    origin_iter, origin_iter + 1);
}

float rms(thrust::host_vector<float> const &a, const size_t origin, const size_t length)
{
    float sumOfSquares = 0.0f;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        sumOfSquares += a[origin + i] * a[origin + i];

    return std::sqrt(sumOfSquares / float(length));
}

void segmented_rms_host(thrust::host_vector<float> const &array,
                        thrust::host_vector<float> &RMSes)
{
    for (size_t segNum = 0; segNum < numSegs; ++segNum)
    {
        RMSes[segNum] = rms(array, segNum * num, num);
    }
}

int main()
{
    thrust::default_random_engine rng(123456789);
    thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(-1.0f, 1.0f); // excludes 1.0f, but ok for testing

    thrust::host_vector<float> array(num * numSegs);
    thrust::host_vector<float> RMSes_ref(numSegs);

    for (size_t i = 0ull; i < array.size(); ++i)
    {
        array[i] = dist(rng);
    }

    segmented_rms_host(array, RMSes_ref);

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_array(array);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_RMSes(numSegs);

    // Determine temporary device storage requirements
    size_t temp_storage_bytes = 0;
    segmented_rms_device(d_array, d_RMSes, nullptr, temp_storage_bytes);
    // Allocate temporary storage
    thrust::device_vector<uint8_t> d_temp_storage(temp_storage_bytes);

    segmented_rms_device(d_array, d_RMSes,
                         thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_temp_storage.data()), temp_storage_bytes);

    thrust::host_vector<float> RMSes(d_RMSes);
    for (size_t i = 0ull; i < numSegs; ++i)
    {
        if (std::abs(RMSes_ref[i] - RMSes[i]) / RMSes_ref[i] > 1.0e-4f)
        {
            std::cout << "Big deviation detected at i = " << i
                      << ": RMS_ref = " << RMSes_ref[i]
                      << " while RMS = " << RMSes[i] << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting x86 CPUs, you should use SSE acceleration.

Here are some power accelerated examples you can use for testing.
Both MSVC and GCC do a very good job at optimizing the code below.  These cold be further optimized for a single input vector.

I won't go into the details on how to detect the capability of the target CPU, so the code below is not complete. But it does show what you'll need to test for selecting the right function at run-time.

My cpuinfo is a singleton based on this library https://github.com/steinwurf/cpuid

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#include <x86intrin.h>
#else
#include <emmintrin.h> // msvc
#include <immintrin.h> // msvc
#endif

float dot_product_plain(const float* a, const float* b, size_t count) noexcept
{
    float result = 0.f;
    while (count--)
        result += *a++ * *b++;
    return result;
}

float dot_product_avx2(const float* a, const float* b, size_t count) noexcept
{
    auto acc = _mm256_set1_ps(0.f);

    const auto do_8 = [&acc](const float* a, const float* b) {
        acc = _mm256_add_ps(acc, _mm256_mul_ps(_mm256_loadu_ps(a), _mm256_loadu_ps(b)));
    };

    while (count >= 32)
    {
        do_8(a, b);
        do_8(a + 8, b + 8);
        do_8(a + 16, b + 16);
        do_8(a + 24, b + 24);

        a += 32;
        b += 32;
        count -= 32;
    }
    while (count >= 8)
    {
        do_8(a, b);

        a += 8;
        b += 8;
        count -= 8;
    }
    if (count)
    {
        alignas(32) float buf_a[8];
        alignas(32) float buf_b[8];

        const auto N = std::min(count, size_t{8});

        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            buf_a[i] = a[i];
            buf_b[i] = b[i];
        }
        for (size_t i = N; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            buf_a[i] = 0;
            buf_b[i] = 0;
        }
        do_8(buf_a, buf_b);
    }

    auto acc2   = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(acc, _mm256_set_epi32(0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4));
    auto acc128 = _mm256_castps256_ps128(_mm256_add_ps(acc, acc2));
    acc128      = _mm_add_ps(acc128, _mm_shuffle_ps(acc128, acc128, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 3, 0, 1)));
    acc128      = _mm_add_ps(acc128, _mm_shuffle_ps(acc128, acc128, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 2)));

    float result = 0;
    _mm_store_ss(&result, acc128);
    return result;
}
```

You should check which of these to execute at runtime, using a cpuid library such as this one: https://github.com/steinwurf/cpuid

Here's what the selection code may look like.

```
dot_product_proc_t get_dot_product_proc() noexcept
{
    if (can_dot_product_avx2())
        return dot_product_avx2;
    if (can_dot_product_sse2())
        return dot_product_sse2;
    return dot_product_plain;
}

bool can_dot_product_sse2() noexcept
{
    return cpu_info()->SSE2();
}

bool can_dot_product_avx2() noexcept
{
    return cpu_info()->SSE() && cpu_info()->AVX();
}
```

Here is the same using SSE2, which targets older processors:

```
float dot_product_sse2(const float* a, const float* b, size_t count) noexcept
{
    auto acc           = _mm_setzero_ps();
    const auto fmacc_4 = [&acc](const float* a, const float* b) {
        acc = _mm_add_ps(acc, _mm_mul_ps(_mm_loadu_ps(a), _mm_loadu_ps(b)));
    };

    while (count >= 16)
    {
        fmacc_4(a, b);
        fmacc_4(a + 4, b + 4);
        fmacc_4(a + 8, b + 8);
        fmacc_4(a + 12, b + 12);

        a += 16;
        b += 16;
        count -= 16;
    }
    while (count >= 4)
    {
        fmacc_4(a, b);

        a += 4;
        b += 4;
        count -= 4;
    }

    acc = _mm_add_ps(acc, _mm_shuffle_ps(acc, acc, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 3, 0, 1)));
    acc = _mm_add_ps(acc, _mm_shuffle_ps(acc, acc, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 2)));

    float result{};
    _mm_store_ps1(&result, acc);

    while (count--)
        result += *(a++) * *(b++);

    return result;
}
```

Note: If you want to change the function to use with a single input (for a small extra measurable gain), here are the corresponding do_8() and fmacc_4() definitions;

```
const auto do_8 = [&acc](const float* a) {
    const auto x = _mm256_loadu_ps(a);
    acc = _mm256_add_ps(acc, _mm256_mul_ps(x, x)); 
};

const auto fmacc_4 = [&acc](const float* a) {
    const auto x = _mm_loadu_ps(a);
    acc = _mm_add_ps(acc, _mm_mul_ps(x, x));
};
```

Comment: Or you just leave it to a library to find out the right instruction set and use it. E.g. [xsimd](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xsimd).

Comment: @paleonix   It's faster to include one file for the OP, since the aim is to help him  evaluate this approach, He can then decide on what to do.

Comment: Whee... it's back (tho' has a formatting issue on my end). I sure am targeting x86 CPUs - thanks for the functions. Can't benchmark the AVX-512 one here alas, but look forward to witnessing the acceleration provided by the other 2 (even if the answer to my original question is now more likely to be 'no')!

Comment: @yodawasacoder  I removed the avx512F, since there was an issue with the origoina sse2 code I posted, and I can't test the avx512F either.

Comment: @yodawasacoder  For this type of computation, CUDA will be much slower, yes.  SMDI optimizes both memory access and uses parallelism,and the gains are very substantial.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to provide something that one can use in production code to avoid the need of maintaining a different version of the function for every targeted architecture.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "For this type of computation, CUDA will be much slower". At least when one doesn't have to include data movement between host and device in the time measurement (i.e. there are more operations producing/consuming this data running on the device). It is just a matter of problem size.

Comment: @paleonix Of course it would be slower, on CUDA.  There is only 1 addition and 1 multiplication per sample.  On the CPU, the bottleneck will be memory access, no code to transfer, and no data to send to the GPU.   It the mah was more involved, maybe there would be something to gain.  Besides, to quote the original question; "the CUDA-based approach is certainly working, but is currently a lot slower than host code".  The SMDI code above can process 100Msample in 18ms (> 5.5 Gsps) on a not so extraordinary Ryzen 2600.

Comment: Other than matrix multiplication pretty much all GPU use-cases are memory bound. That doesn't mean that they are better off on a CPU. The RTX 3070 has a memory bandwidth of 448 GB/s. You wont get near that with most CPUs. Caches and prefetching make it a bit more complicated, but your argument is just nonsense. OP hasn't posted his CUDA code and I never said that for his particular problem(-size) the GPU is better, but your statement is way too general.

Comment: @paleonix For such a small computational load, the entire SMDI code is effectively as fast as reading from memory.  That can only be faster than reading and sending to the device.  If the data was already on the GPU, because of previous worrk being done there, or if the results were to be used for further GPU processing that would be a totally different matter, of course.  But that doesn't seem to be the case.  ... and  CUDA is not available on every computer, so there will always be a need for a CPU based fallback method.  What is the actual throughput of the thrust code?  That's what matters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251119/discussion-between-paleonix-and-michael-roy).

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Using your avx2 function (with immintrin.h not emmintrin.h) accelerates the code in the question by a factor of ~5!

Comment: That's about what I get, too.

Answer (score 1):

With a CUDA kernel, you can accumulate sum of squares in cuda threads' private registers then run a reduction on the results, per thread-block for each subarray. Something like this (not exact codes):

```
template<int V, int U>
__device__ void kernel1(float * values, float * results )
{
    float reg = 0.0f;

    // choosing segment by block index
    // 1 segment = 1 block
    int segment = V*blockIdx.x; 

    // accumulation
    for(int i=0;i<V;i+=blockDim.x)
    {
        // choosing element of subarray by local thread id
        int index = threadIdx.x + i;
        if(index<V)
        {
          // squares summed
          reg += values[segment+index] * values[segment+index];
        }
    }


    // init reduction array
    __shared__ float reduced[blockDim.x];
    reduced[threadIdx.x]=reg;

    syncthreads();

    // reduction
    // assuming blockDim.x is a 2^integer value
    for(int i=blockDim.x/2;i>0;i/=2)
    {
        if(threadIdx.x<i)
            reduced[threadIdx.x]+=reduced[threadIdx.x+i];

        syncthreads();
    }

    // only 1 thread should write the result
    if(threadIdx.x == 0)
       results[blockIdx.x]=sqrt(reduced[0]/V);
}
```

then either on a second kernel or on CPU, those greatly reduced numbers (from V to 1) can be further reduced similarly if you need a total sum of all sub-arrays.

First part of kernel is work-efficient, all block-threads are used to reduce the numbers from V=2000 to T=128 or 256. Then the second part applies reduction with enough steps to reduce from 128 or 256 to 1 then one of the threads writes to a unique position on results array. This part has half the efficiency due to unused threads in block. But if the block size is bigger than number of pipelines per SM unit, it should be a bit less of a loss (such as only 64 pipelines and blocksize=512).

After tuning kernel parameters, data transmission performance can be optimized by using pinned array and/or pipelining the process like pushing U/8 of work to GPU & doing another U/8 of work inside GPU, at the same time.

For U/8 chunk size, there are 9 stages in pipeline

```
pipeline stage --- read from RAM to VRAM --- compute on GPU
1                  (U/8)1                      no work yet
2                  (U/8)2                      (U/8)1
3                  (U/8)3                      (U/8)2
4                  (U/8)4                      (U/8)3
5                  (U/8)5                      (U/8)4
6                  (U/8)6                      (U/8)5
7                  (U/8)7                      (U/8)6
8                  (U/8)8                      (U/8)7
9                  no more data                (U/8)8
```

considering that the algorithm is memory-bandwidth bottlenecked, the computations would be mostly hidden behind all the data transmissions so that it would look like just data transmission overhead in the end. Copying data should be up to tens of gigabytes per second but less than or equal to RAM bandwidth max.

So, it would be hard to beat an optimized AVX(or even SSE) CPU version that gets close to RAM-bandwidth. But at least CPU would be free to do other work.

Without pipelining, profiler shows expected memory-dependent performance for settings U=500 and V=2000 using 256 threads per block (means 500 blocks used):

Input copy: 2.7 milliseconds at 1.4GB/s (equivalent to 0.74 GFLOPS)

[image]

Kernel run: 97 microseconds (equivalent to 20 GFLOPS alone) (performance would vary with u,v)
Also still bottlenecked heavily by GT1030 graphics card's memory bandwidth that is too low. (expect 200-400 GFLOPS for high-end GPUs)

[image]

Output copy: 8.8 microseconds.

Comment: The default (no SMDI) c++ code does the loading, the multiply and add (2 OPS) of 1,000,000 samples (200 x 5000)  in 1about 800us (2.4 GFlops), with sse2, around 260us (7.6 GFlops), and avx2 in around 170us (11.8 GFlops), which is not bad for a few lines of single-threaded code that does not require a library. Optimization by the CPU and the compiler allows for loading data while the multiply and add of the previous set of values are being computed.  It is indeed very difficult to beat.  If needed, a dot product computation can relatively easily be parallelized on several cores,